# How should I quote a translation that includes brackets from the translator?

Tags: writing-style, translations, quotation

I would like to use a quotation of a translation. However the translation contains bracketed material inserted by the translator (a gloss?). What should I do with the bracketed material since brackets in quotes generally indicates I have altered the original?

For instance, this is the exact original of one section I would like to quote (the brackets are in the original)-

> [This do] in the assurance that all these have not run in vain, but in faith and righteousness, and that they are [now] in their due place in the presence of the Lord, with whom also they suffered.

But I would like to change "they" to something else for clarity (my addition is in double brackets) -

> [This do] in the assurance that all these have not run in vain, but in faith and righteousness, and that [[Ignatius, Rufus, and other dead saints]] are [now] in their due place in the presence of the Lord, with whom also they suffered.

How do I correctly insert changes to the quotation while also indicating the originally bracketed material is in fact original? Do I drop the brackets? Use double brackets as here? Use "(sic)" to indicate original brackets? Something else entirely?

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, explain it  to the reader. For example: Singly-bracketed material is from the translator; doubly-bracketed material is added here.

Comment: I was able to rework my material around the quote so that I didn't need to include my own brackets and just noted in my footnote that the brackets are in the original. But I would still like to know if there is an "official" way to deal with these types of situations; I've run into them before. The 8th edition of Turabian's Handbook doesn't include anything about it.